# How to reset where my branch is pointed from master to develop

Tags: git

I created a branch `tool-testing` and a pull request to merge into `master`

This is how I created the branch `git checkout -b tool-testing master`.
After doing some work I created a PR, it was approved but was told not to point to `master`. Instead, point my branch to `develop`.

How would I point to the branch named `develop` now?

Comment: is `master` merged into `develop` once in a while?

Comment: i believe that's the new approach the team is taking @eftshift0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should rebase the branch on top of `develop`:

```
git rebase master tool-testing --onto develop`
```

It is now like you started working on the branch from `develop` instead of `master`. Then you can force-push the branch and you need to change the target branch of the PR to `develop` instead of `master`.